# Make pixel intensity dependant on distance from mouse

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

I am rendering my scene in a 512x512 canvas, my goal is to have the pixel intensity change according to how far away the pixel is from the mouse cursor. But it doesn't seem to change at all. I try multipling by a large number, then it's all white.
[image]

```
    var ico = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(0.3,0), light_mat);
    ico.position.x = 0;
    ico.position.y = 0;
    ico.position.z = -3;
    scene.add(ico);


        var render = function() {
        vec.set(
        ( mouse_x / 512 ) * 2 - 1,
        - ( mouse_y / 512 ) * 2 + 1,
        0.5 );

        vec.unproject( camera );

        vec.sub( camera.position ).normalize();

        var distance = (ico.position.z-camera.position.z ) / vec.z;

        pos.copy( camera.position ).add( vec.multiplyScalar( distance ) );
        console.log(pos.x+":"+pos.y+":"+pos.z);

         ico.material.uniforms.mouse.value = pos;
         requestAnimationFrame(render);
         renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

...

<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="light_f">
varying vec3 pos;
varying vec2 uv_pos;
varying vec3 norm;
uniform vec3 mouse;
void main() {
    vec4 tex = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    float ang = dot(mouse,norm);
    float dis = 0.1*distance(mouse,pos);
    gl_FragColor = tex*dis; 
}
</script>
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="light_v">
uniform vec3 mouse;
varying vec2 uv_pos;
varying vec3 norm;
varying vec3 pos;
void main() {
    uv_pos = uv;
    norm = normal;
    pos = position;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
</script>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you just track a `PointLight` to your mouse position? Light technically serves to scale the color intensity relative to the position (and sometimes angle and/or orientation) of the light.